# Solve the equation $y=xy''+y''^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $y=xy''+y''^2$.

I have tried to solve it but I can't recognize what type of equation I have learnt.

Comment: Analytical solving seems impossible.Probably only way to solve is by numerics.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Can you help me how to solve by numerics? Thank you.

Comment: To solve I need initial,boundary conditions."Solve is by numerics",I mean visualize solution on the graph.

Comment: There is the constant solution $y=0$. Always look for those first when you see some complicated nonlinear ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$y=xy''+y''^2$

$\dfrac{y}{y''}-y''=x$

$\dfrac{y'}{y''}-\dfrac{yy'''}{y''^2}-y'''=1$

Comment: Not OP, but I'm wondering how this helps. You still get a non-linear ODE